# Disable default value in minibuffer in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, customization, default-value, minibuffer

I'm using **query-replace-regexp** very often and there are very long expressions from time to time.

My problem is the following:

```
Query replace regexp (default foo -> bar):
```

Is there a possibility to hide the default expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `minibuffer-electric-default-mode`, the default will disappear as soon as you type something into the minibuffer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple advice does the job:

```
(defadvice query-replace-read-from (before no-default activate)
  (setq query-replace-defaults nil))
```